# Multiple MySQL DATETIME columns

Tags: mysql, sql, database, datetime

I am designing a simple ordering system, and want to track multiple dates per order.

- Date Ordered
- Date Filled
- Date Shipped
- Date Received

Currently my plan is to just use DATETIME columns for each of these dates per order, something like

```
purchase_order
--------------
id             INT(10) (pk)
date_submitted DATETIME
date_filled    DATETIME
date_shipped   DATETIME
date_received  DATETIME
```

Is there a better practice for this situation? The only other thing I can think of is having an event table and then a purchase_order_event join table.

```
event
---------------------------------
id                   INT(10) (pk)
description          VARCHAR(64)


purchase_order_event
---------------------------------
id                   INT(10) (pk)
event_id             INT(10) (fk)
purchase_order_id    INT(10) (fk)
event_date           DATETIME
```

Is this needlessly complex? It's more flexible but the overhead would be fairly substantial. Which way would incur a larger hit to performance?

I have tried to look up best practices related to this situation but couldn't find anything.

Thanks!

Comment: it depends on a lot of things but joining is probably a slower operation than an additional column, especially if those columns aren't indexed or keys.

Answer (score 0):

if purchase_order_event is useful or required in any other table such as purchase_return_event table where one column might refer to the id of purchase_order_event then you may separate it in different table (purchase_order_event) otherwise you may keep the whole event in one table (purchase_order).

Actually it refers to the normalization principle of the database design.